# Twitter Streaming API with Python Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, location, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

I've been playing with the Twitter Streaming API using the Tweepy library. I started by following my own account and streaming my own tweets as I posted them, which worked fine.

I then attempted to stream a fairly large region's tweets ([30,-85,31,-84]), to which I initially seemed to receive no data. I then started receiving 'Location Deletion Notices', or 'scrub_geo' messages, and have only ever received those since. I changed my code back to the previously working follow code, but I continue to receive 'scrub_geo' messages and not statuses from my profile.

Here's the script I'm using:

```
# Import the necessary methods from tweepy library
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

# Other libs
import json

# Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API
access_token = "<my_access_token>"
access_token_secret = "<my_secret_token>"
consumer_key = "<my_consumer_key>"
consumer_secret = "<my_consumer_secret>"


# This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        #try:
        #    json_data = json.loads(data)
        #    print json_data['created_at'] + " " + data['text']
        #except:
        print "Data " + str(data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print "Error " + str(status)
        if status == 420:
            print("420 error.")
            return False


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)

    # Start streaming with right parameters
    #tallahassee=[30,-85,31,-84]
    #stream.filter(locations=tallahassee)           <---- previously used 
    stream.filter(follow="<my_user_id>")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your coordinates are reversed. Since we're dealing with `GeoJSON` always do `(long,lat,alt)` or `(x,y,z)`

So you'll need to provide `tallahassee=[-85,30,-84,31]`. Always provide longitude first same as you would do `(x,y)` in math.

There are some places, like google maps, that do latitude first. You just have to be careful as to which proper format you're dealing with.

Comment: First off, thanks for the correction on the coordinates. Making a request using those coordinates is allowing me to stream tweets, and I'm no longer receiving "scrub_geo" requests.

I'm still a little confused on why I was receiving the "scrub_geo" requests even after I was no longer requesting location-based tweets, but since it works now I'm happy.

Comment: You're welcome. Were you still using `locations=tallahassee` without the coordinates? That you were getting scrub_geo

Comment: No, that line was commented out, as it is in the code above. I was using the `follow=<user_id>` parameters while receiving scrub_geo.

Comment: Maybe that time you ran it without commenting it by accident. Other than that I'm not entirely sure. Can you still replicate it? Also does `follow=<user_id>` represent a person's `id` correct?